# How can an object know if it has been allocated on the stack or the heap?

Tags: c++, constructor, memory-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I tell if an object is statically or dynamically allocated on the constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014440/how-can-i-tell-if-an-object-is-statically-or-dynamically-allocated-on-the-constru)

```
struct Foo {
    Foo ();
};

int main ()
{
    Foo foo;                   // Case A
    Foo * p_foo = new Foo ();  // Case B
}

Foo :: Foo ()
{
    if (allocated_on_stack) {
        // Case A
    }
    if (allocated_on_heap) {
        // Case B
    }
}
```

Can Foo's constructor distinguish these two cases?

Comment: Why would you need this?

Comment: there is no portable way to distinguish that, you should really ask yourself why you need this

Comment: I'm sure we had this question before but I cannot find it.

Comment: @pmr we had this question in similar ways a lot of times, it seems quite common, though I can not remember anyone coming up with a real good reason on why this is even needed.

Comment: @pmr: It's http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014440/how-can-i-tell-if-an-object-is-statically-or-dynamically-allocated-on-the-constru

Comment: @PlasmaHH and I'm sure no one ever will come up with a reason. This should be a FAQ which explains why you are doing something wrong, should you need something like this and possibly some implementation specific ways and hacks how to do it.

Comment: Voted as duplicate -- strictly speaking this wants to distinguish "stack" vs "heap" (probably meaning automatic vs dynamic), while the other wants to distinguish static vs. dynamic, so there is a difference. Same basic issue, though, and same answer as far as portable code is concerned. On a specific implementation, there may be tools or techniques for stack-inspection that let you check whether `this` is an address on the stack of the current thread, or of any thread in the current process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer to the question is no.

There are theoretical solutions, for instance you could replace `new` (on class or global level) and keep track of all `new` allocated pointers and compare to this list to your `this` pointer in the constructor.

```
struct Foo {
    Foo ()
    {
        //Check if `this` is in s_instances
    }
    void* operator new(size_t size)
    {
        void* pointer = ::new(size);
        s_instances.push_back(pointer);
        return pointer;
    }
    void operator delete (void* pointer)
    {
        //remove from s_instances and call global delete
    }
    static std::vector<void*> s_instances;
};
```

(This code won't catch Foo allocated with `new Foo[count]`)

Why do you need this though?

Answer (score -1):

There is no platform independent way. There are few user defined ways. Few of them are,

(1) You may have to put a flag(as a `private` variable) and check the same.

```
struct Foo {
  const bool isHeap;
  Foo (bool heap = false) : isHeap(heap) {}
};
```

(2) Keep track inside overloaded `new`.

```
struct Foo {
  static set<Foo*> heap;
  void* operator new (size_t size)
  {
    void *p = malloc(size);
    heap.insert(<p inside this set>);
  }
};

Foo :: Foo ()
{
  // check heap.find() for heap allocation
}
```

**Edit**:
Above solutions offer the way to know if the variable is automatic (generally on stack/data segment) or dynamic (generally on heap segment).

Comment: This will not reliably detect stack allocation, as the object could be in static storage.

Comment: Note that (2) distinguishes between the two cases in the question, but does not in general distinguish between automatic and dynamic storage duration. For example, if another class `Bar` has a `Foo` as a data member, and then the `Bar` is heap-allocated, `Foo::operator new` of course isn't called but the `Foo` is "on the heap".

Comment: @Steve, `Foo` is on the heap but the variable is still automatic (means we don't need to worry about its deallocation and destruction).

Comment: @PlasmaHH, I am not offering solution for `static` storage. It's just that if the variable is on heap or not.

Comment: Just saying, as the OP had some `if(allocated_on_stack)`

Comment: @iammilind: that's not what automatic means, "automatic storage duration" is defined in 3.7.2. If the questioner were to explain the purpose of the distinction, then we could figure out how this `Foo` data member should be classified, but it's not on "allocated on the stack".

Comment: @Steve, you are correct; it's definitely not allocated on stack. I was trying to distinguish between automatic (generally on stack) and dynamic (generally on heap). Thanks for pointing that out.