# Detect dynamically allocated object?

Tags: c++, memory-management

Can I check if an object (passed by pointer or reference) is dynamically allocated?

Example:

```
T t;
T* pt = new T();
is_tmp(&t); // false
is_tmp(pt); // true
```

#### Context

I perfectly realise this smells like bad design, and as a matter of fact it is, but I am trying to extend code I cannot (or *should* not) modify (of course I blame code that isn't mine ;) ). It calls a method (which I can *override*) that will `delete` the passed object among other things that are only applicable to dynamically allocated objects. Now, I want to check whether I have something that is okay to be `delete`d or if it is a temporary.

I will never pass a global (or static) variable, so I leave this undefined, here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I tell if an object is statically or dynamically allocated on the constructor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014440/how-can-i-tell-if-an-object-is-statically-or-dynamically-allocated-on-the-constr)

Comment: Note that the other (albeit older) question has already been closed as duplicate of this question, so it's probably not a good idea to close this one as duplicate of the other (circular reference).

Comment: `enum class Alloc { by_static, by_thread, dynamic, automatic };` then `T t{Alloc::automatic};` or `T* pt = new T{Alloc::dynamic};`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not portably.  Under Solaris or Linux on a PC (at least 32 bit Linux), 
the stack is at the very top of available memory, so you can compare the
address passed in to the address of a local variable: if the address
passed in is higher than that of the local variable, the object it
points to is either a local variable or a temporary, or a part of a
local variable or temporary.  This technique, however, invokes undefined
behavior right and left—it just happens to work on the two
platforms I mention (and will probably work on all platforms where the
stack is at the top of available memory and grows down).

FWIW: you can also check for statics on these machines.  All statics are
at the bottom of memory, and the linker inserts a symbol `end` at the
end of them.  So declare an external data (of any type) with this name,
and compare the address with it.

With regards to possibly deleting the object, however... just knowing
that the object is not on the heap (nor is a static) is not enough.  The
object might be a member of a larger dynamically allocated object.

Comment: Well, I had a similar thought but my subconsciousness immediately discarded it as *dangerous and creepy*. Thanks for confirming this :)

Comment: It's a very interesting idea to examine the value of the pointer, but somehow it feels so very, very wrong :-) What if the object is a member of dynamically allocated object?

Comment: @bitmask It's definitely not something I'd want to try in portable code, or if my application depended on it.  (I used it in a couple of `assert`, once, to ensure that the object was dynamically allocated; there are better ways of doing this, but I'd only been using C++ for 6 months then, and didn't know them.  And of course, if the test ever did cause a problem, we could remove the `assert`.)

Comment: Also runs into problems if you're running multithreaded, in which case stacks for the additional threads are generally allocated on the heap...

Comment: @Chris Dodd That too.  Although you could probably run all of the thread startup functions through a common point and keep track of their stack addresses.  But I used this before threading existed, so the issue never came up.  (And as I said: I didn't use it in production code---only for debugging.  I am definitely **not** recommending it.)

Answer (score 3):

In general, as DeadMG said, there's no way you can tell from a pointer where it comes from. However, as a debugging or porting or analyzing measure, you could add a member `operator new` to your class which tracks dynamic allocations (provided nobody uses the explicit global `::new` -- that includes containers, I'm afraid). You could then build up a `set<T*>` of dynamically allocated memory and search in there.

That's not at all suitable for any sort of serious application, but perhaps this can help you track where things are coming from. You can even add debug messages with line numbers to your operator.

Comment: Certainly good for debugging, but I already know who calls what, so this falls under *serious application*.

Comment: @bitmask: In production code your requirement for a function to delete an object **optionally** depending on how it was allocated is very troublesome. (For example, you can probably never use your object safely in a container.) The problem with the `new` overloading is that you cannot prevent people from using `::new`, either. So there's really no good solution, and anything you do would depend that you can guarantee that all those things that sidestep your tracking don't happen.

Comment: I know, *troublesome* doesn't even begin to accurately describe what I'm doing here.

Comment: You could override global ::new (and ::new[] and ::delete and ::delete[]) and track every piece of heap allocated memory, but this is not cheap, nor easy.

Comment: @Chris: You cannot override global placement new. (For a very good reason!!)

Answer (score 0):

No, it's impossible to know. You *should* fix the bug. In the least case, you can use a smart pointer (like shared_ptr) and give it an empty custom destructor if you don't want it to be deleted.

Comment: I'm extending/interfacing with code I cannot change (especially not the signature). So I have very limited options. However, I can *decorate* objects at will, so I will go with that, but I wanted to avoid that overhead if you could simply check with some language built-in.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the dynamic memory allocator code itself, you could scan the internal structure and see if the current pointer is in its allocated list/stack/area or however it is being stored.  Quite often they are stored as linked list style structs and it wouldn't be too hard to scan for your var's address.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it should be possible
because you can check if the memory is on the heap or on the stack
This is going to be highly platform depended code

First you have to get the range of the heap, and then you have to check if the passed memory adress is in this range...
(sounds simple, but the first step is probably tricky :-)  )

Comment: It is certainly possible (see James Kanze's answer) but a terrible hack, so I'm not going to do it like this.